# Flip Items In a Single Row In a Matrix

Tags: java, string, matrix, row, swap

I want to basically inversely swap items in a single row in a matrix.
For example if this is a row in a int matrix:

```
--*---*-
```

Then when it gets inversely swapped it would be:

```
-*---*--
```

I would need to do this to values that are equal to "*" in a matrix
This is what I have. I'm not even sure if it will work, and I also get a out of bounds exception. This matrix "image" is a String matrix.

```
public void flipHorizontal(){
    for (int i=0; i<image.length; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<image[i].length; j++){
            if (image[i][j].equals("*")){
                if(j<(image[i].length-1)/2){
                    image[i][(image.length-1)-(image[i].length)-j]="*";
                    image[i][j]="-";
                }
                else
                    image[i][(image[i].length-1)-j]="*";
                    image[i][j]="-";

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is unclear. Do you want to swap every single element in the row i.e. just reverse the entire row, or just reverse the positions of all `*`s? Give an example for a diverse row like `AB*CDE*F`.

Answer (score 0):

The line that seems to be causing the error is line 6:

`image[i][(image.length - 1) - (image[i].length) - j] = "*";`

I don't see why you need this number: `(image.length - 1)`. It is how many rows there are, and I don't see why that is useful for flipping a single row.

Also, Your loops are iterating from 0 to `image.length` (or `image[i].length`), which will give you one more iteration than you need, as a length of 4 will have indexes of 0 to 3 and not 0 to 4. In order to fix this, simply iterate from 0 to `image.length